# product feed Data import in google analytics via management API

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, data-import

I want to import product data in my google analytics account via management api. I tried a lot with google PHP client but the error is  (400) Invalid string value: 'custom'. Allowed values: [cost]'. I don't want to upload cost data but i want to import custom data and that is product feed.

Comment: Welcome to stack you need to add some code before we can help you.

Comment: Are you using the uploads resource? It sounds like you are trying to use the dailyUploads resource, which is only for cost.

Answer (score 3):

You can upload product data to [Google Analytics using the Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtDataImport#product). Below is an example in PHP. Perhaps if you post your code and compare.

```
/**
 * Note: This code assumes you have an authorized Analytics service object.
 * See the Data Import Developer Guide for details.
 */

// This request uploads a file to a particular custom data source.
try {
  $analytics->management_uploads->uploadData(
    '123456',
    'UA-123456-1',
    '987654321',
    array(
      'data' => file_get_contents('example.csv'),
      'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
      'uploadType' => 'media'));
} catch (apiServiceException $e) {
  print 'There was an Analytics API service error '
    . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();
} catch (apiException $e) {
  print 'There was a general API error '
    . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();
}
```